# Form layers for fields in Access

Tags: ms-access

A very simple problem to which I cannot find a solution:

I have a form with 2 (will be more in future) pages. So far I have completed the first page (Main) and now I'm about to do the second page. However, some fields are showing up on both pages.

How do I "anchor" the fields to a specific page so they don't show elsewhere?

Comment: By "pages", do you mean you've added a Tab Control to your form?

Comment: The tab control itself has Page(s), I have solved the problem (very confusing why it didn't work the "regular" way). Answer is below.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you have pages of even height, and set for the form AutoSize to True.

Also, hide the vertical scrollbar and implement your own paging control.

Answer (score 0):

1) Go to Design View

2) Cut out the fields (ctrl+X) which are in wrong place

3) Go to sheet property and manually select the desired page location

4) Insert the fields there (ctrl+V)

For some reason it didn't work for me in any other way (ie. I couldn't select my page with a simple click on the page itself, I had to select it through properties).

Comment: You should be able to select an individual page by clicking a given page tab twice. Also to note: if you have any events your using vba/macros on, when you cut and paste the control to the page, the link to the vba/macro will be broken (the code will still be there though). To reinstate the link to your vba/macro, just simply click on the [...] button in the control's properties on the event tab for each event that needs reinstating (no need to rewrite the code).

Comment: That is the strange part - the page did not get selected no matter what I tried, the only way that worked was selecting it through "Property Sheet". And yes, you are correct about the code link getting broken, but that is easily fixed ^_^.